# Java: Adding the same action listener to muliple combo boxes

Tags: java, callback, actionlistener, anonymous-types

I created an action listener that listens if there is any change with a **departingStop** (a combo box object)

```
departingStop.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
     public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
          //Lots of code here
     }
});
```

I would like to also add this action listener to another combo box (finalStop) without having to create a separate listener like so:

```
finalStop.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
     public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
          //Lots of code here
     }
});
```

How can this be achieved? Thank you

Comment: this action listener is anonymous you need a reference that is set to both

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can assign the listener to a variable...

```
ActionListener listener = new ActionListener() {
     public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
          //Lots of code here
     }
};
```

And then add it multiple times...

```
departingStop.addActionListener(listener);
finalStop.addActionListener(listener);
```

Answer (score 2):

as commented above, you are implementing an anonymous listener you need a reference that is set to both:

```
ActionListener foo = new ActionListener() {
     public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
          //Lots of code here
     }
};

departingStop.addActionListener(foo);
finalStop.addActionListener(foo);
```

Answer (score 0):

If your IDE makes it difficult to set arbitrary listener on GUI components, put the common listener functionality into a separate method and call that method from both combo boxes' listeners:

```
departingStop.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
     public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
          commonGutsOfListener(arg0);
     }
});

departingStop.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
     public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
          commonGutsOfListener(arg0);
     }
});

private void commonGutsOfListener(ActionEvent arg0){
      //Lots of code here
}
```